# Api request with some data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api

In my project the API requires some data to be passed that is :

- Bearer Token
- Body - {email: [email_address]} e.g. {email: “mayank@gmail.com”}
- Params - Your name i.e https://1234.amazonaws.com/alphabet/mayank

I am doing this in reactjs.

But I am confused how to use params.

My try:

```
  method: 'POST',

  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer abcd',

  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'mayank@gmail.com'
  })

};
fetch('https://1234.amazonaws.com/alphabet/mayank')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data,
    });

  },
```

But this is not working.

Comment: can you share sandbox link?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your parameters to the fetch request in an object like this. Read more about how to make post requests [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```js
fetch('https://1234.amazonaws.com/alphabet/mayank',
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer abcd',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'mayank@gmail.com'
  })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      data: data,
    });

  },
```